# Can we register new users in Vonage programmatically using Vonage API or SDK?

Tags: java, messaging, vonage

I'm working on a Messaging Application and for sending message to WhatsApp I'm using Vonage Messaging API. New users can signup to my application, but for these new users I'm not sure how can I register them to Vonage so they can use their own number for sending messages.

Is there any way to register/create new users on Vonage programmatically? Is there any API or SDK for this?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeb_QX8rdKD2WOM5-0rZ10C9rzPsMzqlGL-Aduh7_nM0EEutw/viewform

I have found this form that we have to submit for user registration on Vonage. It's missing in Vonage documentation or maybe not clearly mentioned.